# Splitting a string and get a number

Tags: javascript, jquery, string

I have a string how this:

```
string = "(NUMBER_ID) Comments ... (a number can be here...)";
```

I'd like to get `NUMBER_ID`, only the first content between `()`

Comment: `string.split(')').shift().replace(/\D/g, '')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var string1 = "(NUMBER_ID) Comments ... (a number can be here...)";

alert(string1.split("(")[1].split(")")[0]);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p557ygj3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using regular expression it can be like this:

```
var match = "(NUMBER_ID) Comments ... (a number can be here...)".match(/\((.*?)\)/);
```

Outputs an array:

```
["(NUMBER_ID)", "NUMBER_ID"]
```